# Regular Expression throwing up errors C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a line of text for which I am creating a regular expression. I have used rexex101.com to check against and the resulting regular expression I created is error free. This is the line of text...

```
    <Msg Date="2015/04/29" Time="12:13:39:187" DateReceived="2015/04/29" TimeReceived="12:13:39:187"><Layer Name="MC"><SourceLayer Name="GUI" /><Message Name="OperatorLogin" Id="1" Status="Successful" /></Layer></Msg>
```

This is the regular expression...

```
    [<][a-zA-Z]\w+\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=]"(?<date>(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2})[\/\-](?<month>\d{1,2})[\/\-](?<day>\d{1,2})))"\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=]"(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2}:(?<milli>\.?\d{0,3})))"\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=]"(?<date2>(?<year2>(?:\d{4}|\d{2})[\/\-](?<month2>\d{1,2})[\/\-](?<day2>\d{1,2})))"\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=]"(?<time2>(?<hour2>\d{2}):(?<minutes2>\d{2}):(?<seconds2>\d{2}:(?<milli2>\.?\d{0,3})))"[>](?<logEntry>.*)
```

However, when I bring it into my program it throws up errors such as:
'Unexpected character'
'Invaid expresson term'
'Unrecognised escape sequence'
I thought using the @ symbol at the beginning would prevent it reading slashes as escape characters etc.

This is how it looks within the program...

```
                string strRegXPattern = @"([<][a-zA-Z]\w+\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=]["'](?<date>(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2})[\/\-](?<month>\d{1,2})[\/\-](?<day>\d{1,2})))["']\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=]["'](?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2}:(?<milli>\.?\d{0,3})))["']\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=]["'](?<date2>(?<year2>(?:\d{4}|\d{2})[\/\-](?<month2>\d{1,2})[\/\-](?<day2>\d{1,2})))["']\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=]["'](?<time2>(?<hour2>\d{2}):(?<minutes2>\d{2}):(?<seconds2>\d{2}:(?<milli2>\.?\d{0,3})))["'][>](?<logEntry>.*))";
```

I don't understand this? I wonder if it has something to do with the quotation marks "" or angle brackets <> I have tried putting them into [], () ["'] etc but it makes no difference. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you are using RegEx to parse XML, seems an overly complicated way of doing this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Comment: Hi, yes I know it seems a bit messy to use RegEx but I have a whole bunch of files some xml, some html, some plain text. They're all formatted differently. I have to go though them all and extract the date and time so they can all be ready in together in a List, in order of date and time.  I used HtmlAgility Pack for the html files, and RegEx for the text files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the standard (emphasis mine):

> In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim, the **only exception** being a *quote-escape-sequence*.

So try changing `"` with `""`:

```
string strRegXPattern = @"([<][a-zA-Z]\w+\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=][""'](?<date>(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2})[\/\-](?<month>\d{1,2})[\/\-](?<day>\d{1,2})))[""']\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=][""'](?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2}:(?<milli>\.?\d{0,3})))[""']\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=][""'](?<date2>(?<year2>(?:\d{4}|\d{2})[\/\-](?<month2>\d{1,2})[\/\-](?<day2>\d{1,2})))[""']\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=][""'](?<time2>(?<hour2>\d{2}):(?<minutes2>\d{2}):(?<seconds2>\d{2}:(?<milli2>\.?\d{0,3})))[""'][>](?<logEntry>.*))";
```

Comment: Yes, that was it @AlexD. Thank you so much. It's always the little things that throw me when using RegEx.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a verbatim string, i.e. `@""` then you need to escape quotes by doubling them up...

So: `"` becomes `""`

```
string strRegXPattern = @"([<][a-zA-Z]\w+\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=][""'](?<date>(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2})[\/\-](?<month>\d{1,2})[\/\-](?<day>\d{1,2})))[""']\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=][""'](?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2}:(?<milli>\.?\d{0,3})))[""']\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=][""'](?<date2>(?<year2>(?:\d{4}|\d{2})[\/\-](?<month2>\d{1,2})[\/\-](?<day2>\d{1,2})))[""']\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=][""'](?<time2>(?<hour2>\d{2}):(?<minutes2>\d{2}):(?<seconds2>\d{2}:(?<milli2>\.?\d{0,3})))[""'][>](?<logEntry>.*))";
```

Visual studio should make it very obvious where these quote characters are, as the style will change as it thinks the string has ended.

Comment: Yes @musefan, you are correct. It did throw up squiggly lines. I thought I was getting around that by using [" ']. I was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

In a C# string literal which starts with `@` there is just one special character: `"` if you need this character you have to escape it with another `"`:

so your regexp should look like this:

```
string strRegXPattern = @"([<][a-zA-Z]\w+\s[a-zA-Z]\w+[=][""'](?...
```

Note the double double quotes.

**BUT**

What you are trying to read is an xml string. You should use a xml library to read this. Do nbot reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `XElement` and parse the data as XML? Your data looks a valid XML.

```
var xelement = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse("<Msg Date=\"2015/04/29\" Time=\"12:13:39:187\" DateReceived=\"2015/04/29\" TimeReceived=\"12:13:39:187\"><Layer Name=\"MC\"><SourceLayer Name=\"GUI\" /><Message Name=\"OperatorLogin\" Id=\"1\" Status=\"Successful\" /></Layer></Msg>");
var reslt = xelement.DescendantsAndSelf("Msg");
var time = reslt.Where(p => p.HasAttributes && p.Attributes("Time") != null).Select(p => p.Attribute("Time").Value).FirstOrDefault();
var date = reslt.Where(p => p.HasAttributes && p.Attributes("Date") != null).Select(p => p.Attribute("Date").Value).FirstOrDefault();
var dateReceived = reslt.Where(p => p.HasAttributes && p.Attributes("DateReceived") != null).Select(p => p.Attribute("DateReceived").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Output:

[image] [image] [image]

And you can manipulate further using `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse`.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @stribizhev. I am not familiar with XElement. I will give it a try.

Comment: Sure, I do not insist. In case you receive invalid XML data, this will fail. But you will get a warning the data is corrupt. With regex, you won't get a match, and there'll be no warning. If the datetime format changes, you will have to change the regex. Here, if you use `DateTime.Parse`, you can access the information about the days, months, years, days of week, etc. Please don't understand me wrong, I love regular expressions, but in this case, I believe you do not need them *when dealing with valid XML data*.